# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" when testing a macOS command line project in Xcode 9.3

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift4, xcode9.3

I'm developing a command line application for macOS and I have the following issue: I have the following test case in Xcode

```
import XCTest
@testable import Assembler

class ParserTests: XCTestCase {

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
}

override func tearDown() {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    super.tearDown()
}

func test_commandType_returnRightTypeForAcommands() {
    let parser = Parser()

    // Invocation
    let commandType = "A_COMMAND"

    // Assertion
    XCTAssertEqual(commandType, "A_COMMAND")
}

}
```

And this is the `Parser` class:

```
import Foundation

class Parser {

    func commandType(for command: String) -> String {
        return "A_COMMAND"
    }

}
```

When I run the tests, the following compilation error appears:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Assembler.Parser.__allocating_init() -> Assembler.Parser", referenced from:
      AssemblerTests.ParserTests.test_commandType_returnRightTypeForAcommands() -> () in AssemblerTests.o
  "type metadata accessor for Assembler.Parser", referenced from:
      AssemblerTests.ParserTests.test_commandType_returnRightTypeForAcommands() -> () in AssemblerTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What's happening?